# Previewing video on change of input files with Video.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video.js

i´m traying to preview a video on change of an input type file, I get the error when I put the src getted by the input type file on the  of the video.js, this is my code:

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
<video id='my-video' class='video-js vjs-16-9' controls preload='none' data-setup='{}'>
         <source type='video/mp4' class="source-video" id="source-video">
    </video>
```

JS:

```
$("#customFile").change(function () {
    var input = document.getElementById('customFile');;

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
        var dataURL = reader.result;
        var output = document.getElementById('source-video');
        output.src = dataURL;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
```

});

The error on the player of video.js is:
**No compatible source was found for this media.**

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure this is working by getting the value of the input, you've may got something like the localPath of the file that can't be accessed by the the SRC attribute.

there is two option:

1 - use a backend where you can upload the file and then you retrieve the url on your server and set your src attribute to display it

2 - i have use dropzone.js for a project its a bit hard to setup but I know that you can get the data of the file and that will work on your src attribute
( I know there is a preview option for picture but I don't know for video but I know you can get at least the "data://" or 32bit (I don't know what the exact name) url to get the content of the selected )